# Entering data with WebSQL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-sql

I'm having some trouble using WebSQL for my Chrome Extension. (This is my first time using it)
I found this tutorial and am trying to adapt it to my needs: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/

Heres my code:

```
var favourites = {};
favourites.webdb = {};

favourites.webdb.db = null;

favourites.webdb.open = function () {
  var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
  favourites.webdb.db = openDatabase("favourites", "1", "Favourites Database", dbSize);
};

favourites.webdb.onError = function(tx, e) {
  alert("There has been an error: " + e.message);
};

favourites.webdb.onSuccess = function(tx, r) {
  // re-render the data.
  // loadTodoItems is defined in Step 4a
  favourites.webdb.getAllTiles(loadTiles);
};


favourites.webdb.createTable = function() {
  var db = favourites.webdb.db;
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                  "tiles(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, name, colour, width, linkURL, imgURL)", []);
  });
};


favourites.webdb.addTile = function(tileName, tileColour, tileWidth, tileLinkURL, tileImgURL) {
  var db = favourites.webdb.db;
  db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tiles(name, colour, width, linkURL, imgURL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
        [tileName, tileColour, tileWidth, tileLinkURL, tileImgURL],
        favourites.webdb.onSuccess,
        favourites.webdb.onError);
   });
};

function loadTiles(tx, rs) {
  var rowOutput = "";
  var todoItems = document.getElementById("tiles");
  for (var i=0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
    rowOutput += renderTile(rs.rows.item(i));
  }

  tiles.innerHTML = rowOutput;
}
function renderTile(row) {
  return "<a href='" + row.tileLinkURL + "'>" +
      "<div class='mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect tile' style='background-color:" + row.tileColour + "; width:" + row.tileWidth + "px;'>" +
      "<img class='tileimg' src='" + row.tileImgURL + "'>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</a>";
};


favourites.webdb.deleteTile = function(id) {
  var db = favourites.webdb.db;
  db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM tiles WHERE ID=?", [id],
        favourites.webdb.onSuccess,
        favourites.webdb.onError);
    });
};


function init() {
  favourites.webdb.open();
  favourites.webdb.createTable();
  //favourites.webdb.getAllTiles(loadTiles);
};
```

I am getting an error when I try to add data to the database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1wye.png

Could somebody explain what's going wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be, that `favourites.webdb.db === null` and therefore does not have a method `transaction`.

For that reason, I would check if `init` is actually invoked. (If so, then check if the verison parameter of openDatabase is correct. In the docs I find, it should rather be `"1.0"` than just `"1"`.

Comment: I also suggest you @Splycd to consider to use IndexedDB instead of WebSQL since w3c group stopped working on a spec. If you having trouble  using IDB try Dexie.js which is really helpful wrapper for IDB.